# SQl performance b/w like and trim

Tags: oracle

Which would be better to perform search on a column in SQL table :-

like or trim.

As this column has the spaces either on the starting or at the end so both serves the purpose but which one would be faster.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up a test and see how they are performing. In example below I've used dbms_utility.get_time. I tested the same input for both functions and repeated the test alternatively to exclude any exterior influence.
It is a "plsql environment", if I can call it this way, you should replace the query with actual table and actual tests and do a more "sql" test.

```
declare
v_start number;
v_end number;
time_trim number:=0;
time_like number:=0;
cnt_trim number:=0;
cnt_like number:=0;
begin
for N in 1..10 --repeat test
loop
    for type_oper in 1..2
    loop
        v_start := dbms_utility.get_time;
        for k in (
            select 'abc   ' as col from dual connect by level <= 100000 
            union all
            select 'ccc   ' as col from dual connect by level <= 100000
            union all
            select 'acbc   ' as col from dual connect by level <= 100000
            union all
            select '   acbc   ' as col from dual connect by level <= 100000
        )
        loop
        if type_oper = 1 then
            if trim(k.col) = 'abc' then cnt_trim := cnt_trim + 1; end if;
        else 
            if k.col like '%abc%' then cnt_like := cnt_like + 1; end if;
        end if;
        end loop; --end loop table
        v_end := dbms_utility.get_time;
        if type_oper = 1 then 
            time_trim := time_trim + v_end-v_start;
        else 
            time_like := time_like + v_end-v_start;
        end if;

    end loop; --end loop type
end loop; --end loop repeat test
dbms_output.put_line('time trim:'||time_trim/100);
dbms_output.put_line('time like:'||time_like/100);
end;
/
```

Result:

> cnt trim:1000000 time trim:6.33
>   cnt like:1000000 time like:5.83